# ASP.NET MVC: jQuery UI and other scripts loaded unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, optimization

I've got a ASP.NET MVC project on the run. On page load, the easing function of easeOutQuad is immediately used. However, sometimes when I load the page, it says there is no function called easeOutQuad, which no doubt, means the jQuery UI library has not been loaded properly. Other times it works well.
I've checked the loading order in the output source code a couple of times, and I can assure you that the order - jQuery, jQuery UI, inline script, shouldn't be the key to the problem.
Any insight into this issue?

PS: The connection quality may be associated with this phenomenon. Given this I still don't know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a single example of your code it's tough to say.  However, I am guessing, given the nature of your issue, that your call to easeOutQuad is not wrapped in the jQuery document-ready method.  Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //your call to easeOutQuad
});
```

If it is already wrapped in this call, or doing so does not affect your issue, please post enough code to replicate the issue so we can be of further help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put the scripting code at the end inside the <body> tag. I think that's nearly equivalent to the code above, is it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, they accomplish different tasks.  Placing your scripts at the end of the body allows the most possible HTML to load before subjecting your visitors to potential JavaScript issues (e.g. slow loading files).  Placing JavaScript that is dependent on jQuery, especially that which operates on the DOM, inside of the document-ready hook ensures that jQuery is ready before you begin your operations.

Comment: That's interesting. Actually some time later, after I put the code I had dynamically inserted with jQuery into the static HTML file and then I tried to interact with it, things work out fine. Thanks for your great answer. I was wrong for such a long time.